# Strong Markov property for Poisson Random Measures

Tags: probability

I have one question about strong Markov property for Poisson random measures (PRM for short) i.e. Poisson point processes. I beleive that PRM's posseses that property but I cannot find a reference!? 
I will try to describe the problem. Consider a time-space Poisson point process $N$, for instance, $N=PRM(\lambda \times \mu)$ with state space $[0,\infty)\times (0,\infty]$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, and measure $\mu$ is given by $\mu(x,\infty]=1/x$.
Further, let $T$ be a stopping time for the process $N$, i.e.

$$\{T\leq t\} \in \sigma\{N|_{[0,t]\times (0,\infty]}\}$$

where $N|_{A}$ denotes standard restriction of a measure to some set $A$.

So, as far as I understand, if PRM possesses a strong markov property, then we can conclude

$$N([0,T+c]\times (0,\infty])= N([0,T]\times (0,\infty])+N'((T,T+c]\times (0,\infty])$$

for arbitrary $c>0$ where $N'$ is also PRM independent of $N$ and equal in distribution with respect to $N$.

I'm wondering is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add LaTeX code by placing the expression in dollar symbols for inline math and double dollar for centered math.